How do I go about making the tcurve par of this lamp?

I want to make the curve part of this lamp but I don't know how to. a youtube tutorial or an explanation here is appreciated

hello, create a torus, keep only 1/4, extrude its tips?

Import reference picture with shift+a > Image > Reference
Create a bezier curve, erase points, instead use Curve Pen tool to create  the curve you need,  in Edit Mode, adjust the handles by rotating them so the bend is correct.
Go to Curve Properties go to Bevel>Round and give it a small Depth Value.
Duplicate the curve object then in Curve Properties change the factor start and end points so you can easily create the silver ring.
(Set the materials for the objects.)


Create a torus, set its thickness and amount of vertices in the Operator Box, only keep 1/4th of it:

Extrude each tip:

